Trying to update my outdated android app (Native)
I've gone back to try and update my old app which is essentially a dark filter app that turns on when you move the phone around
It runs as it should do on most phones however it ends up crashing on new ones (Android 14)
I've found it that its mostly due to some permission changes which i need to update (feel free to correct me if im wrong)
This is the error im getting:
Explain: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.fresh.ShakeforBlackScreen,  PID: 11340 java.lang.RuntimeException:  Unable to start service com.fresh.ShakeforBlackScreen. ShakeOverlayService@ 1912596 with Intent { cmp=com.fresh.ShakeforBlackScreen/ . ShakeOverlayService (has extras) }: java.lang.SecurityException:  Starting FGS with type mediaProjection callerApp=ProcessRecord{ 6cd9fca 11340:com.fresh.ShakeforBlackScreen/ u0a197}  targetSDK=34 requires permissions: all of the permissions allOf=true [android.permission. FOREGROUND_ SERVICE_ MEDIA_ PROJECTION]  any of the permissions allOf=false [android.permission. CAPTURE_ VIDEO_ OUTPUT,  android:project_media]  at android.app.ActivityThread. handleServiceArgs( ActivityThread. java: 5164)  at android.app.ActivityThread. - $ $ Nest$ mhandleServiceArgs( Unknown Source:0) with tag AndroidRuntime
For the CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT it's a permission only for system apps so im not sure if i should add it in or not
Thank you for your time and help :)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
